# How to add alexgorbatchev SyntaxHighlighter in my WordPress hosted website

Tags: wordpress, syntax, web-hosting, syntaxhighlighter

I want to manual configuration, don't want use any plugin.. tell me the step by step solution of it.

Comment: You could have found this info yourself by investigating a bit: [SintaxHighlighter - Usage](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Usage).

Comment: Here is a guideline link: http://www.snippetnuggets.com/howtos/webTipsAndTricks/miscellaneous/use-syntax-highlighter-in-website-blog-html.html